# k-NN average distance bound

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I need to show the following inequality concerning the k-NN algorithm:
$$
$$
Data $ S = \{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n\}  $ is split in the $ \leq k$ parts:

$$
S_j = \{ X_i L i - (j-1)   \lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor + 1,\ ...\ , j\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor\}, 1 \leq j \leq k
$$

So for example for $ S = \{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_{10}\}$ and $k=2$ we got $S_1 = \{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5\}$ and $S_2 = \{X_6, X_7, X_8, X_9, X_{10}\}$

$$
$$
For the $X_{1, j}(X)$ as 1st nearest neighbour of $X$ in $S_j, j \leq k$
I need to show that:

$$
\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{j}(X) - X||} \leq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{1, j}(X) - X||}
$$

$X_{j}(X)$ stands for j-th next neighbour of X
$$ $$

A far as I understand, this inequality states that the on average the distance between $X$ and it's j-th neighbour is bounded by the average of distances between $X$ and it's first neighbour in the j-th partition of the data set. Does it make any sense? If not, what is the correct intuition? I'd be extremely thankful for any hints on how to aproach this proof.

Comment: Your statement that “$X_j(X)$ stands for j-th next neighbor of X”—insofar as you mean the 2nd, 3rd, 4th... nearest neighbors of X—suggests that j indexes by distance from X.  But in your inequality, j actually indexes the different partitions.  So I can’t reconcile your stated description of $X_j(X)$ with your inequality’s use of j.

Comment: @wklm I think you should be referencing the $k$-means algorithm, rather than the $k$-nearest neighbor algorithm. $k$-nearest neighbor is a classification method used to determine the class of an unlabeled point, and there are not necessarily $k$ classes that the data is sequestered into. $k$-means on the other hand explicitly sequesters the data into $k$ subsets. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm versus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Answer (score 1):

Your use of $j$ to index both the partitions and the nearest neighbors within each partition is confusing in terms of notation, but the key issue is that you've misstated the core inequality.  It should read:

$\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{j}(X) - X||} \geq \frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{1, j}(X) - X||}$

That's because, within any given partition, the distance to $X$'s closest neighbor, ${||X_{1, j}(X) - X||}$, must, by definition, be less than or equal to the distance between $X$ and all of its more distant neighbors (whose distances will be equal only if there are multiple points equidistant from $X$):

${||X_{j}(X) - X||} \geq {||X_{1, j}(X) - X||}$

Just as that definitional inequality establishes a lower bound on how close the points within some particular partition lie to $X$, so too does the average across all those minimal, nearest-neighbor distances establish a more generalized bound.  For example, if you take the second closest point from each partition and average across each of those distances to $X$, you will necessarily get an average distance that is equal to or greater than the average across the nearest neighbor distances.  (Again, those two averages would be equal only if there was a tie between the first and second nearest point within every individual partition).  More generally, there is no way to draw a point from each partition such that the average of the selected points' distances to $X$ is less than the average of the distances between $X$ and its nearest neighbor within each partition.  That's the point of the inequality and the sense in which the average of the nearest neighbor distances from each partition establishes a lower bound across all the partitions.

Comment: Hi Bill, many thanks for your answer! As much as I agree with your conclusion, I believe the inequality isn't misstated. $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{1, j}(X) - X||}$ stands for the mean distance across the $j$ partitions, which as you observed is greater than $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{j=1}^{k}{||X_{j}(X) - X||}$, mean distance to $j$ nearest neighbours of $X$. Does it make sense?

Comment: Am I correct that we can make no assumptions about distances based on partition assignments?  If so, don’t we need a different variable, perhaps $i$, to specify the $i$th closest point within some partition $j$?  I’m confused by your use of j to index both the “$j$-th partition” and the “$j$-th nearest neighbour” because I had assumed those were independent indices.

Comment: $j$ is the number of data set partitions, $S_1, S_2, ..., S_j$.  $k$, is the number of neighbors of $x$ in the whole data set $S$. We assume $j \leq k$

Comment: Right, and your notation $X_1,j(X)$ to specify the first nearest neighbor in the $j$-th partition makes a lot of sense to me.  Extending that notation, we could use $X_2,j(X)$ to capture the second nearest neighbor, right?  So don’t we need $X_i,j(X)$ to capture the $i$-th closest within the $j-th$ partition?

Comment: no, For every partition $S_j$ we only consider a single point $p \in S_j$ such that from all the points in $S_j$, the distance between $p$ and $X$ is minimal, in other words, the nearest neighbor of $x$ in $S_j$

Comment: You have used $k$ to specify the number of partitions, but traditionally the $k$ in k-NN specifies the number of nearest neighbors to be included, which can vary, right?

Comment: That's exactly the case, apologies for the confusion. The data is split in $k$ or fewer partitions